# Failing to create Project from SVN with Eclipse and SVNKit

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit, eclipse-mars

Using Eclipse (Mars) and the SVNKit 1.7.8 i want to create a "Project from SVN". It works fin untill the window "Select Resource". If i click "Finish" here it starts loading and after finishing returns to the window "Select Resources" without changing anything. I don't even get an error message...

But it is possible to browse the repository via "SVN Repository Exlporing". So why is creating a project from SVN not working?

[image: "Select Resouce" window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling Eclipse with a fresh workspace and SVNKit 1.8.1, now it works fine.